# Get color of single pixel after mouse click on Graphics

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

I'm trying to get the color of a single pixel when I click with the mouse on a point.

I'm using `Graphics` and I successfully drew a 500x500 red shape but when I try to get the color of a pixel at the `mouseX`/`mouseY` position (above the red shape I drew) it prints out `(0,0,0)` and not the red RGB values.

```
    public void getColor(int mouseX, int mouseY)
    {
        Color myColor = Color.RED;
        globalGraphics.setColor(myColor);
        globalGraphics.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
        int color = getRGB(mouseX, mouseY);
        int red = (color >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
        int green = (color >>8 ) & 0x000000FF;
        int blue = (color) & 0x000000FF;
        System.out.println(red+" "+green+" "+blue);         
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int mouseY = e.getY();
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        getColor(mouseX,mouseY);
    }
```

Comment: What is `getRGB` here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

0,0,0 is black if I remember correctly, which is exactly the color of the pixel that the mouse is at, because the mouse is black, so I would test wheater the mouse interferes with your measurement and try mouseX-1, mouseY-1